# Retrieving A Function From A WebhookScript Global Variable

Tags: function, types

In WebhookScript, [I can store a function](https://docs.webhook.site/webhookscript/reference.html#functions) in a variable with:

```
sub = function(a, b) {
    return a - b
}
```

I'd like to store a function in a Global Variable so that I can use it in multiple Custom Actions. But if I've saved the above function as `$sub$` then

```
sub2 = var('$sub$')
subX = sub(1,2)
```

causes an error:

> Trying to invoke a non-function 'string' @ line...

And

```
function subX(a,b){
    var('$sub$')
}
```

when `sub` only contains `return a - b`, doesn't work either.

Obviously I need to convert the string to a function but I'm not sure whether that's possible.

I know this is a bit of an obscure language but if anyone knows how this can be done in similar languages like JavaScript and PHP, I'm happy to test out any guesses...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here is to remove the `function` section and just enter the script, which inherits the execution scope so if my global variable `$script$` is:

```
return 'hello ' + a
```

Then I can execute the function with:

```
a = 'world'

value = exec(var('$script$'))
echo(value)
```

(credit to Webhook.Site's support team for explaining this)